# Google Annotation Chart background color

Tags: javascript

I don't think there is a direct way to change Google Annotation Chart's background color, is there any way I can change the color through, e.g., Google visualization APIs(which should work on all visualizations)? Could anyone show me an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not see any difference between your question and the referenced question. Please provide images or extend your question with what you want to accomplish.

Comment: The linked Q/A is for common Google Charts, which works fine for plots like bar chart or pie chart, but the one I'm using is called "Annotation Chart" (please find in google) which is different from other charts and does not have any ready-to-use configurations on background color. You can open a w3school code page and try it out, I guarantee you it won't work.